# Set number of labels on my x-axis

Tags: matlab, date, axis-labels

Today I'm having problems with the x-axis in MATLAB. I plot some daily quantities together with the dates.

```
quantline= plot( quantDates(1:end,1), quantwithdrawn, '-.b', 'LineWidth', 2) ;
```

BUT it doesn't matter what combination of `datetick`, `set` `gca`, `xlim`, etc. I try, the best x-axis numbering I can manage is:
[image]

I want at least 3 months for every year, how can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, solved this myself with taking the length of the plotted vector, then xlim([ 0, quantlen+60]);
     datetick;
     set(gca,'XTick',1:90:quantlen);
     set(gca,'XTickLabel',datestr(period(1:90:quantlen),12));

Comment: If you have already solved, you can post your ans yourself and accept it so that people are clear as to ans is solved.